# Adding Razor Pages from another project into Blazor Project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, blazor, .net-6.0

I've moved the scaffolded Identity Razor Pages from a blazor server app into a separate project(RCL). There are no build/compile or runtime errors. The project runs.

[image: Razor Pages]

When I browse to `/Identity/Account/ForgotPassword` I get:
"Sorry there's nothing at this address"
[image: Nothing at address]

I am calling
`services.AddRazorPages()` in my main blazor project and also have a reference like so in `app.razor`:

```cs
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(App).Assembly"
            AdditionalAssemblies="new[] {
            typeof(DapperIdentity.Controllers.IdentityController).Assembly,
            typeof(IdentityUI.Pages.UsersEditPage).Assembly
            }">
```

The razor pages are in the same project as `IdentityUI.Pages.UsersEditPage` as there are blazor components in there. (Note, the blazor components work.)

Program.cs:

```cs
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

string connectionString;
if (builder.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    var conStrBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
    conStrBuilder.Password = builder.Configuration["ConnectionStringPasswords:Development"];
    //conStrBuilder.CommandTimeout=60;
    conStrBuilder.ConnectTimeout=30;
    connectionString = conStrBuilder.ConnectionString;
}
else
{
    connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
}



builder.Services.AddDbConnectionInstantiatorForRepositories<MySqlConnection>(connectionString);

builder.Services.AddDapperIdentityWithCustomCookies(TimeSpan.FromDays(10), false, true);

builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider<DapperIdentity.Models.CustomIdentityUser>>();

builder.Services.AddMyAppServices(builder.Environment);

StaticWebAssetsLoader.UseStaticWebAssets(builder.Environment, builder.Configuration);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddServerSideBlazor();
builder.Services.AddMudServices();
builder.Services.AddHttpClient();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapBlazorHub();
app.MapControllers();


app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => { 
    endpoints.MapBlazorHub(); 
    endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host"); 
    endpoints.MapRazorPages(); });




app.Run();
```

I'm a little stuck on where to go from here in order to get the razor pages working from my blazor server app.

Comment: Can you post your Program.cs?

Comment: Do you use `app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapBlazorHub();
                endpoints.MapFallbackToPage("/_Host");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();});` in the program.cs ?

Comment: Does this help? ... https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio#rcl-pages-layout

Comment: @NeilW I moved everything into `Pages` folder in the RCL... still not working

Comment: If you can share your sample project(Note: Hide your sensitive info) for us, it could be faster to help you to solve current issue.